# react-router-redux 5.x with HashHistory

Tags: react-router, react-router-redux

In react-router-redux 5.x, ConnectedRouter takes place of HashRouter.

I cannot find much information about v5.

How do I use hash-based routing?

Comment: Does anyone has an idea???